# Copy Worksheets From One Workbook into Another

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy all the sheets from one workbook other than the first sheet to another workbook and then once the sheets have been copied to the other workbook, close it. Here is what I have for my code so far. Right now, it is copying all the sheets from Workbook `SD09_KW.xlsm` and pasting them into the Workbook `Pending SD09` which is the correct location. However, I would like it to copy all the worksheets in `SD09_KW` other than the first sheet. It also is making copies of all the sheets in `Pending SD09` and saving them inside the workbook too which I do not want it to do. Any help would be great! Thanks.

```
Sub CopySD()
Dim DataWorkbook As Workbook, PendingWorkbook As Workbook, Sheet As Worksheet

    Set DataWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Documents\SD09_KW.xlsm")
    Set PendingWorkbook = Workbooks("Pending SD09")

    For Each Sheet In DataWorkbook.Sheets
        Sheets.copy After:=PendingWorkbook.Sheets(PendingWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
    Next
    PendingWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

UPDATE: I have made a few changes, however, nwo I am getting an error of `"Object doesn't support this property or method"` in line `DataWorkbook(i).Sheets.copy After:=PendingWorkbook.Sheets(PendingWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)`

Here is the updated code:

```
Sub CopySD(sysnum As String) ' copies over the SD tabs created into the pending doc workbook
Dim DataWorkbook As Workbook, PendingWorkbook As Workbook, i As Long

Set DataWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Documents\SD093_KW.xlsm")
Set PendingWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Documents\Pending SD093.xlsx")

For i = 2 To DataWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    If Not SheetExists(sysnum, PendingWorkbook) Then ' SD tab not already saved to pending workbook
        DataWorkbook.Sheets(i).copy After:=PendingWorkbook.Sheets(PendingWorkbook.Worksheets.Count) ' save SD tab to pending workbook
    End If
Next
PendingWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For i = DataWorkbook.Sheets.Count To 2 Step -1  
    DataWorkbook.Sheets(i).Delete
Next i

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not save it under the new name and then just delete the first sheet?

Comment: @SJR I could, but the data in `DataWorkbook` will always be changing, so I need to be able to save the new data in the workbook to `PendingWorkbook` If I did how you suggested, I would have to combine all the workbooks each time a new one is made

Comment: So you're not just copying from one file to another? In your code, you could add a check in your loop based on the sheet name or index (>1) before copying. I fail to see how that code can be copying the destination sheets also.

Comment: Also why do you close the file without saving?

Comment: `Sheet.copy`, not `sheets`.

Comment: @SJR it should automatically save since it is on OneDrive

Comment: @SJR I am looking to copy all the sheets from one file to another, but the sub needs to be able to repeat itself if the `DataWorkbook` is updated with more sheets that will need to be copied over to the `PendingWorkbook`

Comment: `DataWorkbook.Sheets(i)` - you're referencing the index of the sheet, not the workbook.

Comment: To keep your name out of the code and to make it work for anybody's OneDrive folder, you can e.g. use `Environ("OneDrive") & "\Documents\SD093_KW.xlsm"`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thank You! I didnt even notice I forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy/Delete Worksheets

- Note the mistakes in your codes where you have used:

  - `Sheets.Copy...` instead of

    ```
    Sheet.Copy...
    ```
  - `DataWorkbook(i).Sheets.copy...` instead of

    ```
    DataWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Copy...
    ```
- Note the inaccuracies (inconsistencies, mistakes if the workbooks contain charts) in your codes where you have used:

  - `... In DataWorkbook.Sheets` instead of

    ```
    ... In DataWorkbook.Worksheets
    ```
  - `... After:=PendingWorkbook.Sheets(PendingWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)` instead of

    ```
    ... After:=PendingWorkbook.Sheets(PendingWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    ```
  - `... To DataWorkbook.Sheets.Count` instead of

    ```
    ... To DataWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    ```

**Copy All But the First Worksheet**

**`For Each...Next`**

```vb
Sub CopyForEach()

    Dim DataWorkbook As Workbook
    Set DataWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Documents\SD09_KW.xlsm")
    
    Dim PendingWorkbook As Workbook
    Set PendingWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Documents\Pending SD09.xlsx")

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim FoundFirst As Boolean
    
    For Each ws In DataWorkbook.Worksheets
        If FoundFirst Then
            ws.Copy After:=PendingWorkbook.Sheets(PendingWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        Else ' skip first
            FoundFirst = True
        End If
    Next ws
    
    PendingWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

**`For...Next`**

```vb
Sub CopyForNext()

    Dim DataWorkbook As Workbook
    Set DataWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Documents\SD09_KW.xlsm")
    
    Dim PendingWorkbook As Workbook
    Set PendingWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Documents\Pending SD09.xlsx")

    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 2 To DataWorkbook.Worksheets.Count ' 2 means skip first
        DataWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Copy _
            After:=PendingWorkbook.Sheets(PendingWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    Next i
    
    PendingWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

**Delete All But the First Worksheet**

- After `PendingWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True` you will use either

  ```
  DeleteAllButFirstWorksheetForEachNext DataWorkbook
  ```

  or

  ```
  DeleteAllButFirstWorksheetForNext DataWorkbook
  ```
- Of course, use shorter names for the procedures e.g. `DeleteAllButFirst`.

**`For Each...Next`**

```vb
Sub DeleteAllButFirstWorksheetForEachNext(ByVal wb As Workbook)
    
    Dim wsCount As Long: wsCount = wb.Worksheets.Count
    If wsCount < 2 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim WorksheetNames() As String: ReDim WorksheetNames(1 To wsCount - 1)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long
    Dim FoundFirst As Boolean
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If FoundFirst Then
            n = n + 1
            WorksheetNames(n) = ws.Name
        Else ' skip first
            FoundFirst = True
        End If
    Next ws

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb.Worksheets(WorksheetNames).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

**`For...Next`**

```vb
Sub DeleteAllButFirstWorksheetForNext(ByVal wb As Workbook)
    
    Dim wsCount As Long: wsCount = wb.Worksheets.Count
    If wsCount < 2 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim WorksheetNames() As String: ReDim WorksheetNames(1 To wsCount - 1)
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Long
    
    For i = 2 To wsCount
        WorksheetNames(i - 1) = wb.Worksheets(i).Name
    Next i

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb.Worksheets(WorksheetNames).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to delete all the sheets from `DataWorkbook` other than the first sheet once they have been copied over to `PendingWorkbook`? I have updated my code however it currently deletes the sheets from `DataWorkbook` one at a time after they have been copied. I would prefer it delete them all at once once they all have been copied over.

Comment: Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Let me it out! Would you be able to add comments for line ` Dim WorksheetName() As String: ReDim WorksheetNames(1 To wsCount - 1)` explaining what it means

Comment: The line `Dim WorksheetNames() As String` means declaring an array of type *String*. The line `ReDim WorksheetNames(1 To wsCount - 1)` means resizing the array from 1 to the number of worksheets **minus 1** because we don't want to delete the first worksheet. When the array's lower limit is 1 then the array's upper limit is equal to the number of elements in the array making it easy to work with.

Comment: I guess I am getting confused why you are looking at the worksheet names? What purpose do they hold?

Comment: I'm writing the names to the array to delete the worksheets in one go with `wb.Worksheets(WorksheetNames).Delete`. It may not have a great impact on the efficiency in this particular case but when e.g. it comes to working with many cells in a range (worksheet), it is priceless.

Comment: Also I am using the Sub CopyForNext in a `For Loop` is there a way to write the `PendingWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True` to close the workbook only after the last worksheet has been copied? Like can i move it to my main sub and call it after I call CopyForNext

Comment: I don't know what your complete project looks like, but I learn most of the time by trial and error when it is reasonable. Create a backup of your files, save everything, uncomment any `.Save` or possibly `.Delete` lines, and give it a try. It is a lot of work but it will eventually pay off.

Comment: In regards to the arrays: You delete a worksheet with e.g. `Worksheets("Sheet2").Delete`. If you want to delete more than one worksheet, you can use the Array function in the following way: `Worksheets(Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")).Delete`. You can do this also manually e.g. select `Sheet2`, hold `Ctrl`, and select `Sheet3` and `Sheet4` and right-click in one of the tabs to select `Delete`. If you would record this, it would produce a similar code to the code with the Array function.

Comment: I have tried the record macro method, however wouldnt the recording only then delete sheets up 4?